# failed to send join request to master elastic search 5.4 cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

I have configured elastic search with 3 nodes My cluster is not able to find the master node

Logs of elastic search

```
[2018-02-24T02:39:39,106][INFO ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [node3] failed to send join request to master [{node1}{MO28S_KZQaih1pd-ERrvIA}{SBwZDgFcTz2xTLOyh2fZAA}{192.168.2.xxx}{192.168.2.xxx:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[node1][192.168.2.xxx:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: NotMasterException[Node [{node1}{MO28S_KZQaih1pd-ERrvIA}{SBwZDgFcTz2xTLOyh2fZAA}{192.168.2.xxx}{192.168.2.xxx:9300}] not master for join request]; ], tried [3] times
[2018-02-24T02:39:42,332][INFO ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [node3] failed to send join request to master [{node1}{MO28S_KZQaih1pd-ERrvIA}{SBwZDgFcTz2xTLOyh2fZAA}{192.168.2.xxx}{192.168.2.xxx:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[node1][192.168.2.xxx:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: NotMasterException[Node [{node1}{MO28S_KZQaih1pd-ERrvIA}{SBwZDgFcTz2xTLOyh2fZAA}{192.168.2.xxx}{192.168.2.xxx:9300}] not master for join request]; ], tried [3] times
```

My elasticsearch.yml file

```
cluster.name: cluster-testing 
node.name: node3
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 192.168.2.xxx
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.2.xxx", "192.168.2.xxx", 
                                    "192.168.2.xxx"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2 
gateway.recover_after_nodes: 2 
gateway.expected_nodes: 3
```

I am not able to find where is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn a node into a master node you need to add

```
node.master: true
```

into elasticsearch.yml.

From your configuration

```
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

at least two of your nodes must set node.master to true

EDIT:

you can find below working configuration for our project (3*masters and 6*slaves):

MASTER:

```
cluster.name: VAL_elasticsearch
node.name: MASTER-${HOSTNAME}
node.data: false
node.master: true
path.data: /data
path.logs: /local/opt/logs
path.repo: ["/home/data_ElasticSearchBackup"]
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
bootstrap.seccomp: false
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ip_master1","ip_master2","ip_masterx"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

SLAVE:

```
cluster.name: VAL_elasticsearch
node.name: DATA-${HOSTNAME}
node.data: true
node.master: false
path.data: /data
path.logs: /local/opt/logs
path.repo: ["/home/data_ElasticSearchBackup"]
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
bootstrap.seccomp: false
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ip_master1","ip_master2","ip_masterx"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

Are you sure all ports are open between all elastic instances ?

Comment: can you share the configuration of all 3 nodes?

Comment: same configuration on 3 nodes same log on 3 nodes

Comment: whether it may be a problem i dont know excactly iam running on a virtual box with 3 ubuntu machines

Comment: are you able to ping/telnet/nc your instances from all of your vm?

Comment: Thamks yes Mumrah iam able to ping and now i fixed it now its working fine.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar error, but my case was a little different.

I was trying to boot up 2 ES nodes on the same machine. I had copied my ES directory to start a new node and I was getting `RemoteTransportException` this exception.

After Googling a little bit I found out that I had to delete `nodes` directory in the copied directory to boot that node. This directory is usually present in `{ES_HOME}/data/nodes` or `/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes`.

Source: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21405

Comment: I had a similar issue and deleting the node folder on the data node servers worked for me. My error message was reporting "failed to send join request to master" ... "found existing node{x}... with the same id but is a different node instance"